# How get the Sequence Number assigned to message by ServiceBusMessage.SendMessageAsync

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

ServiceBusMessage.SendMessageAsync returns after await a task but I don't see how to get from the result the Sequence Number assigned by service bus in a queue for this message.

Is it possible to get the SequenceNumber (similar to [ServiceBusReceivedMessage.SequenceNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceivedmessage.sequencenumber?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusreceivedmessage-sequencenumber)) some other way for each message sent at the time the task returns?

```
ServiceBusMessage newStateMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(newStateJson);
await newStateSender.SendMessageAsync(newStateMessage);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the data that you're looking for does not exist when `SendMessageAsync` returns.  The only way to query the sequence number is to peek or receive the message.

When `SendMessageAsync` returns, Service Bus has acknowledged receipt of the message and assumed responsibility for it, but it has not yet been fully committed to a queue/topic.  The sequence number is assigned by Service Bus when the message is committed.

Comment: Thank you @Jesse Sequire , this feature would really help for audit purposes but I get it that waiting for the commit is likely a worse result most times.

Comment: This is a limitation of the service itself; nothing that the SDK can do to influence it.   If you'd like to open a feature request for the service, the best place to start is by logging an issue here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues